# BLE uuid values

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, uuid

I have noticed that in BLE peripherals often the uuid values of the characteristics are similar to the that of the service they are under. For example if the service UUID is

```
A1EE0100-A572-4B01-A022-0EFD2A7A199C
```

you might see some characteristics under it with the values

```
A1EE0101-A572-4B01-A022-0EFD2A7A199C
A1EE0102-A572-4B01-A022-0EFD2A7A199C
A1EE0103-A572-4B01-A022-0EFD2A7A199C
```

where everything is the same as the service uuid except for the ending of the first section. Is this just a convention people tend to follow or is this required? Is there anything that says the characteristic uuids under a service can't just be basically randomly generated?

Answer (score 3):

This is just a convention and there's nothing (i.e. no specification) that says that the characteristic UUID should be similar to the service UUID. For example, the heart rate service shortened UUID is 0x180D, while the heart rate characteristic is 0x2A37. Similarly the temperature service UUID is 0x1809 and the characteristic UUID is 0x2A1C.

You can find relevant links here:-

- [BLE service UUID and characteristic UUID format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53681336/bluetooth-le-service-uuid-and-characteristic-uuid-format)
- [How do I choose a UUID for my custom service and characteristic](https://novelbits.io/uuid-for-custom-services-and-characteristics/)
- [BLE services: a beginner's tutorial](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/guides/short-range-guides/b/bluetooth-low-energy/posts/ble-services-a-beginners-tutorial)